# ¿A qué se debe el error: "Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null"?

Tags: javascript

Me gustaría saber porque estoy teniendo este error

```js
function printDiv(divName) {
     var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
     var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;

    document.body.innerHTML = printContents;

     window.print();

     document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
}

printDiv(printableArea);
```

```html
<body>
<div id="printableArea" style="display: none;">
      <h1>Print me</h1>
</div>
</body>
```

Y tengo este error:

> Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null
>          at printDiv (first.html:48)
>          at first.html:58`

Esta es la linea 48:

```
var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
```

Y esta la 58:

```
printDiv(printableArea);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error esta aquí:

```
printDiv(printableArea);
```

No existe una variable `printableArea`. Pero si existe un elemento con `ID` igual a `printableArea`.

Solución:

```
printDiv('printableArea'); // Pasar el ID como string
```

Answer (score 2):

Realmente el error creo que es bastante explícito:

> Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null

Lo que significa que estás intentando usar `innerHTML` en un elemento nulo.

El error realmente no te lo da la línea 58 si no la 48, en la cual intentas realizar la siguiente acción:

```
var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
```

Por supuesto, no puedes modificar el HTML de un elemento que no existe, por lo tanto, por eso te da el error, porque `divName` tendría que ser un ID y tu le estás pasando a `divName` la variable `printableArea` (la cual no existe) en vez de un ID.

La sintaxis del método `getElementById` es la siguiente:

```
document.getElementById(elementID)
```

en la cual `elementID` tiene que ser un `String` que represente el ID de un elemento de la página.

Por lo tanto, la corrección a tu problema se realizaría en la línea 58, en la cual le pasas a la función el parámetro `divName`, pasandole el `String` del ID en vez de una variable que no existe.

```
printDiv("printableArea");
```

Por supuesto,también podrías realizar lo siguiente en caso de que quisieras usar una variable:

```
var printableArea = "printableArea";
printDiv(printableArea);
```

Answer (score 1):

Valida primero que el elemento exista:

Modifica tu código de la siguiente manera:

```js
function printDiv(divName) {
 var printContents = document.getElementById(divName);
 
 // Validar que el div exista.
 if (printContents != null || printContents != undefined) {
  // Usar la misma variable.
  printContents = printContents.innerHTML;
  
  var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
  document.body.innerHTML = printContents;
  window.print();
  document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;  
 } else {
  alert('El elemento (' + divName + ') no existe');
 }
}
```